# Weird problems when submitting iOS app to Facebook review team

Tags: ios, facebook, review

FB team is unable to check my Facebook + iOS app. Every time I send it to the team (I tried about 4 times), the review finishes with a failure.

Either  a promo code is not valid (I’m sure that it is 100% working) or they unable to download my binary attached to the submission form (its funny but they send me their own internal URL https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-frc3/t39.3826-6/10333114_442712309165103_1256335019_n.zip/myappname_232586603511009.zip
).

I used to do this without any problems but now (after they redesigned review forms) I stuck with it. Could anybody help me with that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure the promo code and binaries are correct, you can file a bug here: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

You are sure you have no restrictions in place, such as IP/domain checks, etc?